# Parsing issue with textread in matlab

Tags: matlab

given:

```
v = textread(strPathFilename, '%s', 'delimiter', ' ', 'endofline', '\r\n');
```

I want returned 'v' as a cellArray of columns from the file.

but instead I get 1 column of everything parsed by a space.

Desired:

```
file:
1 2 3 4 CR
5 6 7 8 CR
9 10 11 12 CR

v{1}:
1, 5, 9

v{2}:
2, 6, 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textscan` to achieve this:

```
fid = fopen(strPathFilename,'r')
v = textscan(fid, '%d%d%d%d', 'delimiter', ' ', 'endofline', '\r\n')
fclose(fid)
```

This results in

```
v = 

    [3x1 int32]    [3x1 int32]    [3x1 int32]    [3x1 int32]
```

with each of the cells containing one column.

Comment: If the line has varying number of elements, is there a way to have it defined to start at the first element(per line) instead of a circular buffer?

Comment: As long as the number of `%d`'s is larger than the maximum number of columns in a line, the code should work fine, as shorter lines are treated as lines with missing values. Per default, missing values are replaced with 0 unless defined otherwise with the flag `'EmptyValue'`. Please see http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
C = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f %s','Delimiter','\n');
```

I hope this helps.